# Selecting multiple checkboxes in a recyclerview's item and saving them in a Hashmap

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am working on a quiz app which having Match the Matrix type Questions. I want to save selected checkbox data and option also to hashmap.

If the user select Option P and Q from 1st Position in the list then
data should add on hashmap in this format

- `0=1-P|Q|0|0|0` "Option 1"
- `1=2-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 2"
- `2=3-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 3"
- `3=4-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 4"
- `4=5-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 5"

Here zero is value for not selected check-boxes.
Then user selects Option S and T from 3rd Position  then
data should add on hash-map in this format

- `0=1-P|Q|0|0|0` "Option 1"
- `1=2-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 2"
- `2=3-0|0|0|S|T` "Option 3"
- `3=4-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 4"
- `4=5-0|0|0|0|0` "Option 5"

The data should be saved on every checkbox checked or unchecked.
Please refer this image for reference.

[image]

This method return string    `"1-1|1|0|0"`

```
public String MatchtheMatrixSelectionManagement(boolean isChecked,int pos,String getText){
    String csv;

    if (isChecked){

        MultiChoiceAnswerList.set(pos,ConvertPQRSTtoNumber(String.valueOf(getText)));
        String idList = MultiChoiceAnswerList.toString();
        csv = idList.substring(1, idList.length() - 1).replace(", ", ",");
    }
    else {
        MultiChoiceAnswerList.set(pos,"0");
        String idList = MultiChoiceAnswerList.toString();
        csv = idList.substring(1, idList.length() - 1).replace(", ", ",");
    }
    return csv;
}
```

This listener used to save data in hashmap

```
  holder.MTMCheckboxT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String csv = MatchtheMatrixSelectionManagement(holder.MTMCheckboxT.isChecked(),4, String.valueOf(holder.MTMCheckboxT.getText()));
                MTMCheckList.put(position,String.valueOf(csv+" "+mListenerList.get(position).getOptionName()));
                MTCSavetoDatabase();

            }
        });
```

Because there are 5 items in the list so I don't understand how to save all data in hashmap.

Comment: ok.show what have you tried ?

Comment: intend of using hash map use pojo model class

Comment: @AmitVaghela Any Solution?

Comment: what does `idList.length()` return?